# How to make a gridview with the grid cell maximizing the height and width?

Tags: android, gridview

I am currently trying to have a GridView only show pictures with text underneath with 1dp space in between. However, because of the text I am not sure how to fill up the gridview cells completely, and I know maybe since I put a dimension for the height and width of the image items that it does not show filled but how do I fill it?

GridView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/categoryGridView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

</GridView>
```

GridCell xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/categoryImageViewItem"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:background="@drawable/com_facebook_button_blue" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/categoryTextViewItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/categoryImageViewItem"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

how do I actually have the picture fill up everything but leave space for the text programmatically or in the xml

Comment: work with this two android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" in your grideview.

Comment: Well the issue is how do I actually have the picture fill up everything but leave space for the text programmatically or in the xml